# Oracle Regexp_substr to return a value from a yaml string

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am trying to parse the yaml string to a column in SQL.

I have a yaml string in one of the columns like

```
country_cd:GB
postal_town_city:London
zip:CT11 A1Cr
```

I have to write a query to pass the key and get a value. When I pass 'country_cd', I want to receive 'GB'.

I have tried the below script but it is returning 'country_cd:G'. What am I doing incorrectly ?

```
 select trim(regexp_substr('---
 country_cd:GB
 postal_town_city:London
 zip:CT11 A1Cr', '\n?'||'postal_town_city'||'*[:=] *(.+?) *\n?', 1, 1, 'i')) from dual ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with a capture group, we can try:

```
SELECT yaml,
       REGEXP_SUBSTR(yaml_col, '(^|\s)country_cd:(\S+)', 1, 1, NULL, 2) AS country_cd
FROM yourTable;
```

Here is regex [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qavwOY/1).

Comment: The 6th parameter should be 2 (not 1) and this would not get the complete value if the key was `zip`. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a85f4c9140f6d1d6edcde7d6f77d93c8) Also, regex101.com is not great for Oracle regular expressions as Oracle does not support the same range of syntax.

Comment: @MT0 Good catch on that sixth parameter...in my mind I had made the first group non capturing, but of course Oracle regex doesn't allow for that.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `REGEXP_SUBSTR` with the `m` match parameter to parse the string as separate lines:

```sql
SELECT REGEXP_SUBSTR(yaml, '^country_cd:(.*)$', 1, 1, 'm', 1) AS value
FROM   table_name;
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table_name (yaml) AS
SELECT 'country_cd:GB
postal_town_city:London
zip:CT11 A1Cr' FROM DUAL;
```

Outputs:

> | VALUE |
> | --- |
> | GB |

or, you can split the string using simple string functions (which are often quicker than using regular expressions) and then filter for the correct key:

```sql
WITH lines (yaml, line_start, separator_pos, line_end) AS (
  SELECT yaml,
         1,
         INSTR(yaml, ':', 1),
         INSTR(yaml, CHR(10), 1)
  FROM   table_name
UNION ALL
  SELECT yaml,
         line_end + 1,
         INSTR(yaml, ':', line_end + 1),
         INSTR(yaml, CHR(10), line_end + 1)
  FROM   lines
  WHERE  line_end > 0
)
SELECT SUBSTR(yaml, line_start, separator_pos - line_start) AS key,
       CASE line_end
       WHEN 0
       THEN SUBSTR(yaml, separator_pos + 1)
       ELSE SUBSTR(yaml, separator_pos + 1, line_end - separator_pos)
       END AS value
FROM   lines
WHERE  SUBSTR(yaml, line_start, separator_pos - line_start) = 'country_cd'
```

Which outputs:

> | KEY | VALUE |
> | --- | --- |
> | country_cd | GB |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_21&fiddle=a318c5bd151664b7eccd7ff6f57f68e7)*

Comment: Great answer, but note that in practice YAML files can be nested, and the same key name may appear as a subkey multiple times.  Neither regex nor substring operations suffices in this case, so in general a parser is required to extract from a YAML file.